# Store large symbolic data in a binary format efficiently?

Tags: export, data, save, storage

As far as I understand, the [Binary Data](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BinaryData.html) feature of Mathematica can efficiently store raw numbers or elements of a given type to binary files. Is there a way to store a large symbolic expression (read - wild mixture of all possible element types) in a binary format that can be quickly saved and loaded back into memory?

Comment: Why not use `DumpSave`?

Comment: The wdx format is an option: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WDX.html

Comment: @GustavoDelfino actually `BinarySerialize` uses the `WXF` format.

Comment: I have not checked recent versions but WDX used to be way slower than other options. Is this still the case? If it is just for quickly saving and loading on the same computer/Mathematica version then `DumpSave` or export to `MX` format seems to be by far the best bet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`BinarySerialize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html), particularly the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Size"`. It's even better than [`Compress`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html)

```
data = {
   RandomReal[1, {10, 10000}],
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}],
   ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}],
   ExampleData[{"Text", "UNHumanRightsEnglish"}]
   };

ByteCount /@ Through[{BinarySerialize, Compress}[data]]
(* {1027513, 1220720} *)


DumpSave["test1.mx", data];

dataz = BinarySerialize[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Size"];

DumpSave["test2.mx", dataz];

FileSize /@ {"test1.mx", "test2.mx"}
(* {Quantity[1.0258, "Megabytes"],  Quantity[0.915118, "Megabytes"]} *)
```